# Get a system for auto preview of uploaded PDF

Tags: pdf, architecture, woocommerce

I am working on an eCommerce site. We would be selling PDFs. I wish to show the buyer a preview (say 2-3 pages) of the PDF he/she is going to purchase. (Somewhat like the Amazon Look Inside feature) 
What I have in mind is to manually edit each PDF and add it on the sales page. Is there any smart way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) to extract pages of an existing PDF document and re-use them in a new PDF document. This way you could create a kind of preview without much effort:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('original-ebook.pdf');
$pageCount = min(3, $pageCount);

for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    $tplId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplId, null, null, 0, 0, true);
}

// add additional pages with information about the ebook

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Sorry if the question in stupid. Does it ensure that the original PDF cannot be seen when FPDI is used?

Comment: This process is done on the server... so as long as you didn't provide a direct link to your original PDF (e.g. by keeping them outside of the public folder) this should never happen.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your documents all have the same structure, you would have to select the representative pages manually.

What you could do is open the document in Acrobat, and then select the pages to be shown in the Pages panel (or the Page view in Acrobat DC), and extract those pages. This will give you a preview document, you can put in your store.